# How can I decrypt password to login in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

While changing the password I am using this function

```
public function passwordChange(Request $request, $userId)
    {
        $user = User::find($userId);
        $user->password = Crypt::encrypt(Input::get('password'));
        $user->save();
        return redirect('my-profile');
    }
```

So in my mongoDb database password insert in encrypted form, So whenever I have to login in system at that time how can I compare my password with password of database

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {

        $rules = array(
            'company_email' => 'required|email|exists:users,company_email',
            'password' => 'required|string|max:20|min:4',
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            return view('pages.login')->with('v_errors', $validator->errors()->messages());
        } 
        else 
        {
            //get email and query
            $authenticateMe = $request->only('company_email', 'password');
            $user = User::where($authenticateMe)->first();

            if (empty($user)) 
            {
                return view('pages.login')->with('not_exists', 'true');
            }
            //session set
            // Session::put('key', $user->username, $user->file);
            Session::put('key', ['username' => $user->username, 'email' => $user->company_email, 'userId' => $user->id, 'profilePicture' => $user->file]);
            return redirect('my-profile');
        }
    }
```

I am not using php artisan make:auth
will anyone please help??

Comment: Laravel has Authentication build in, have you tried it? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users With that way the password hashing is done for you

Comment: According to requirement I don't have to use that, So I made manual log in system

Comment: Yes, you don't have to. But what's wrong with it? Why making your life complicated? If you check the password yourself you should call `Auth::login($user);` to create a session for that user.

Comment: My senior employee asked me to do that so, and I learn quite a lot in this manual stuff, will you please help me to solve this issue??

Comment: I'm not sure if it is so easy to use a framework without using the framework. But try to change the line `Session::put(..` with `Auth::login($user);`

Comment: Nope, not working

Comment: If you just want to know how a string can be encrypted and decrypted you can find it in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption#using-the-encrypter, just use `Crypt::encryptString()` and `Crypt::decryptString()`. If you want to know something else you should ask a direct question, explain what you are trying and what error message you get.

Comment: See below I have put some error code and try other stuff too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of encrypting the password, use hashing. Laravel has its own documentation about how to use that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing

Comment: If I use hash then also same issue happens

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can not decrypt an encrypted password but you can check user credentials by adding an array of user email & password to Auth::attempt() function Here is a link to the description: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users?

Here is your function using Auth::attempt():

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{

    $rules = array(
        'company_email' => 'required|email|exists:users,company_email',
        'password' => 'required|string|max:20|min:4',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return view('pages.login')->with('v_errors', $validator->errors()->messages());
    } 
    else 
    {
        //get email and query
        $authenticateMe = $request->only('company_email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($authenticateMe)) {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

            //session set
            // Session::put('key', $user->username, $user->file);
            Session::put('key', ['username' => $user->username, 'email' => $user->company_email, 'userId' => $user->id, 'profilePicture' => $user->file]);
            return redirect('my-profile');    
        }else{
            return view('pages.login')->with('not_exists', 'true');

        }
    }
}
```

And do not forget to add `use Auth;` to the function controller